# Profile page for user roles

Tags: users, profiles

I want to create front-end profile for specific user role. We have a user role called 'Brand' and I am looking for a way to make its URL like `www.example.com/brand/brandname`
 
Any idea on how can i achieve this?

Thanks in advance!